# Merge multiple columns based on the first column values

Tags: awk, gawk

I have multiple files (10+) that I want to merge/join into the one output file, for example:

file 1

```
2000 0.0202094
2001 0.0225532
2002 0.02553
2003 0.0261099
2004 0.0280311
2005 0.028843
```

file 2

```
2000 0.0343179
2001 0.036318
2003 0.039579
2004 0.0412106
2005 0.041264
```

file 3

```
2004 0.068689
2005 0.0645474
```

All files have the same two columns are are of unequal length.

The desired output would be:

```
        file1       file2      file3
2000    0.0202094   0.0343179
2001    0.0225532   0.036318
2002    0.02553
2003    0.0261099   0.0395799
2004    0.0280311   0.0412106   0.0686893
2005    0.028843    0.041264    0.0645474
```

I have tried the following code however the values don't align with the first column:

```
awk '{printf($1); for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) printf ("\t%s", $i); printf "\n"}' <(paste file*) > mergedfile.txt
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: I can run this however it doesn't align it to the values in the first column
awk '{printf($1); 
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) printf ("\t%s", $i); printf "\n"}' <(paste file*) > masterfile.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make `awk` run on all those files in one shot, by grouping on the first column entries. The part `map[$1]?(map[$1] FS $2):($2)` is a ternary statement, meaning add to the array map indexed by `$1`, if it was empty or append to the already existing values if it is non-empty.

```
awk '{ map[$1] = ($1 in map)?(map[$1] FS $2):($2); } 
     END { for(i in map) print i, map[i] }' file*
```

To make the output a bit more readable than the output produced by `awk`, pipe the output as

```
awk '{ map[$1] = ($1 in map)?(map[$1] FS $2):($2); } 
     END { for(i in map) print i, map[i] }' file* | column -t > mergedfile.txt
```

Comment: `map[$1] = map[$1]?...` will fail when `map[$1]` is zero. You should be testing ``map[$1] = ($1 in map)?...`` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Done by below script

```
STEP1

awk '{print $1}' file1 file2 file3| awk '{if(!seen[$1]++){print $0}}' >pattern_content

STEP2

for i in `awk '{print $1}' file1 file2 file3| sort | uniq`; do grep "$i" file1>/dev/null; if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then grep $i file1| awk '{print $2}'; else echo "                                "; fi; done > file1_o

for i in `awk '{print $1}' file1 file2 file3| sort | uniq`; do grep "$i" file2>/dev/null; if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then grep $i file2| awk '{print $2}'; else echo "                                "; fi; done > file2_o


for i in `awk '{print $1}' file1 file2 file3| sort | uniq`; do grep "$i" file3>/dev/null; if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then grep $i file3| awk '{print $2}'; else echo "                                "; fi; done > file3_o


step3

 paste pattern_content file1_o file2_o file3_o|sed '1i                 file1          file2               file3'| sed "s/file1/\t&/g"
```

output

```
        file1       file2      file3
2000    0.0202094   0.0343179
2001    0.0225532   0.036318
2002    0.02553
2003    0.0261099   0.0395799
2004    0.0280311   0.0412106   0.0686893
2005    0.028843    0.041264    0.0645474
```