# Merge multiple files by first column

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

My question is similar to this one: [Merge multiple columns based on the first column values](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525747/merge-multiple-columns-based-on-the-first-column-values)

I have multiple files (10+) that I want to merge/join into one output file, for example:

file 1

```
2000 0.0202094
2001 0.0225532
2002 0.02553
2003 0.0261099
2006 0.028843
```

file 2

```
2000 0.0343179
2003 0.039579
2004 0.0412106
2006 0.041264
```

file 3

```
2001 0.03
2004 0.068689
2006 0.0645474
```

All files have the same two columns and are of unequal length. Where there is no entry for the columns (missing in one or several files), I would want a 1. If there is no entry in any file (like 2005) I don't want any output.

The desired output would be:

```
        file1       file2       file3
2000    0.0202094   0.0343179   1
2001    0.0225532   1           0.03
2002    0.02553     1           1
2003    0.0261099   0.0395799   1
2004    1           0.0412106   0.0686893
2006    0.028843    0.041264    0.0645474
```

I have tried to modify the awk code provided by the answer of this other question, but I feel like it could not be possible with that solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `join`:

```
join -a1 -a2 -e 1 -o auto <(join -a1 -a2 -e 1 -o auto file1 file2) file3
```

see in the [man join](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join)

> **-a FILENUM**
> also print unpairable lines from file FILENUM, where FILENUM is 1 or 2, corresponding to FILE1 or FILE2
>
> **-e EMPTY**
> replace missing input fields with EMPTY
>
> **-o FORMAT**
> obey FORMAT while constructing output line

> If FORMAT is the keyword 'auto', then the first line of each file
> determines the number of
> fields output for each line.

Note: join require sorted input, so if those are not sorted (which they are in given samples), sort them first, like:

```
join -a1 -a2 -e 1 -o auto \
    <(join -a1 -a2 -e 1 -o auto <(sort file1) <(sort file2)) \
    <(sort file3)
```

---

#### To apply this on multiple files:

1. join first two files and save output to third file say *`join.tmp`*:

   ```
   join -a1 -a2 -e 1 -o auto file1 file2 >join.tmp
   ```
2. next loop over the rest of the files and update *`join.tmp`* file for every run:

   ```
   for file in rest_files*; do
       join -a1 -a2 -e 1 -o auto join.tmp "$file" >join.tmp.1
       mv join.tmp.1 join.tmp
   done
   ```
3. at the end your *`join.tmp`* would be your final joined result.

---

#### print with header:

```
$ hdr() { awk 'FNR==1{ print "\0", FILENAME }1' "$1"; }
$ join -a1 -a2 -e 1 -o auto \
      <(join -a1 -a2 -e 1 -o auto <( hdr file1) <(hdr file2)) \
      <(hdr file3) |tr -d '\0'
```

for the multiple files version:

```
$ hdr() { awk 'FNR==1{ print "\0", FILENAME }1' "$1"; }
$ join -a1 -a2 -e 1 -o auto <(hdr file1) <(hdr file2) >join.tmp
$ for file in rest_files*; do
     join -a1 -a2 -e 1 -o auto join.tmp <(hdr "$file") >join.tmp.1
     mv join.tmp.1 join.tmp
  done
$ tr -d '\0' <join.tmp >final.file
```

Comment: Hi, although it may be late, I'd be happy to hear from you. I use this code along with filed information as join -1 3 -2 1 -a1 -a2 <(join -a1 -a2 <(hdr file1) <(hdr file2)) > merged_file. But it says that : join: missing operand after '/dev/fd/63/dev/fd/62. Could you please help me out to solve the issue?

Comment: yes, I defined hdr before running the join code, but the error still remains

Comment: Thanks, I try it. So, in the code, join -1 3 -2 1 -a1 -a2 <(join -a1 -a2 <(hdr file1) <(hdr file2)) > merged_file, ">" for output is wrong?

Comment: @Mary, that is wrong in  your code, not the code in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A bit clumsy, but this `awk`-code works. It uses the option of [pseudo-multidimensional arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html) with the SUBSEP concatenation of array indices. Saves all data in RAM, so limited in that case.

```
{x[$1]=$1 ; file[FILENAME]=FILENAME ; y[$1,FILENAME]=$2}

END { for (i in file) { printf "\t%s",file[i] } ; printf "\n",""
      for (i in x) { printf "%s",x[i]
        for (j in file) { if (y[x[i],file[j]] != "")
                             { printf"\t%s",y[x[i],file[j]] }
                          else { printf"\t%s","1"}
        }
        printf "\n",""
      }
    }
```

Output is tab-delimited only, for fixed formats, the printf-commands would need to be adjusted accordingly:

```
    file1   file2   file3
2000    0.0202094   0.0343179   1
2001    0.0225532   1   0.03
2002    0.02553 1   1
2003    0.0261099   0.039579    1
2004    1   0.0412106   0.068689
2006    0.028843    0.041264    0.0645474
```

Comment: This looks fine to me, I leave this open to maybe get a less RAM heavy solution (number of rows is in the milions and up to 300 files). Thank you!

Comment: Can we force this order? sometimes e.g. file 3 would be first

Comment: @pascal Well with GNU's `gawk`, you could set how arrays are traversed. E.g. in dictionary order of indices by adding `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"` as first command in the `END` block - this would make the filenames sorted alphabetically. See: [Predefined array scanning orders](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html)